# Initialize an nginx module's shared memory depending on a server configuration directive

Tags: module, nginx

I'm writing a small nginx module that reads some url pairs from a data file, and then stores its contents on an rb-tree in nginx's shared memory. In the handler's code, the tree contents are matched with the request uri, and a redirection is performed based on certain conditions.
This works fine at the moment. The module kicks in during the postconfiguration phase at the function ngx_http_mymodule_init, where it adds the shared memory and assigns the init function that will be called by nginx later.

```
ngx_http_mymodule_init(ngx_conf_t *cf) {
    [...]
  ngx_http_mymodule_shm_zone = ngx_shared_memory_add(...);
    [...]
  ngx_http_mymodule_shm_zone->init = ngx_http_mymodule_init_shm_zone;           
  return NGX_OK; 
}
```

And that init_shm_zone function is the one that creates the tree, reads the data file, and initializes the tree contents.
But there should be one data file for each virtual server, so I need to read the path for the input data file from an nginx configuration directive, like this:

```
static ngx_command_t ngx_http_mymodule_commands[] = {
  [...]
  { ngx_string("mymodule_input_filepath"),
    NGX_HTTP_SRV_CONF|NGX_CONF_TAKE1,
    ngx_conf_set_str_slot, // should be ngx_conf_set_path_slot i guess...
    NGX_HTTP_SRV_CONF_OFFSET,
    offsetof(ngx_http_mymodule_srv_conf_t, input_filepath),
    NULL },
  ngx_null_command
};
```

...and then use that filepath to open the file and store its contents on shared memory. However, at the ngx_http_mymodule_init function, I can't access the config object, so I can't read the file name.
So, my question is, in which handler or phase should I hook my initialization code, so that I can read the filename from the server config and use it to initialize my shared memory?
It has to be somewhere after the config file has been parsed, and after the shared memory has been created, but before any actual request processing.
I have tried to hook into the init_master and init_process handlers, but I can't seem to find the config object from the cycle object that those handlers receive as parameter...

Comment: Why do you use shared memory at all, if you don't change it and read data only at startup? Or I'm wrong, and your rbtree is changed while processing requests?

Comment: I just need all requests to be matched against a list of redirects that is read from a file at startup. No modifications until a restart/reload. I thought reading it to shared memory would be the only option... is there a better way to do this? (edit: the list would be big, like thousands of possible redirects)

Comment: You don't need shared memory then. You can read it in the heap memory at the configuration stage and save pointer in the conf structure (main, loc or serv does not matter). You should read about [`fork()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29) and [`COW`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write). Nginx forks itself to a bunch of worker processes after the configuration has been read and initialized.

Comment: And, btw, why do you create a new module, and don't use [`map`](http://http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mmcf = (ngx_my_module_conf_t *) ngx_get_conf(cycle->conf_ctx, ngx_my_module);
```

See here for example:
http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/browser/nginx/trunk/src/core/ngx_regex.c#L316

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have tried it but still my ngx_my_module_srv_conf object is NULL. Maybe the method is only valid for MAIN conf objects? Or maybe the init module is too early to have access to it? I will try to find out and post here...

Comment: Of course it's NULL. The "server" conf is chosen only after a request is received. You're probably doing something wrong  by trying to configure shared memory zones on the server level. If you look at any nginx module, that uses shm, you will find that it's always on the main level.

Comment: See http://nginx.org/r/limit_req_zone , http://nginx.org/r/limit_conn_zone , http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cache_path , etc..

Comment: Of course! If you don't have request, you don't know which server it is yet... I will move the shared memory init to the main level and hold the data for all my servers there. Thanks.